# How to reduce React build folder size

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I am new to react programming.I created some react webapp project. After that i excuted npm run build command it is generated build folder with size 32 MB. Inside build folder there is static/js folder. There we have multiple chunk files.

```
232123.chunk.js ==> 3 MB
main.23423.chunk.js.map ==>27 MB
```

I wanted to know will this chunk.map js file impacts my app performance or not. When i do source explorer it is showing 3 MB for bundle view.

Comment: The `*.map` files can be used by developer tools to reconstruct the original source code from the transformed source code (which is what is actually executed in the browser). It's loaded only on demand and shouldn't be pushed to production anyway. 3 MB is still quite large but without knowing what you are doing there is nothing we could say about it.

Comment: Make sure you are minifying and gziping your app. Please share your application bundler(webpack, parcel, etc) file

Comment: I am not using any webpack file, I am using react inbuilt command

Comment: Where is the documentation for that inbuilt command? Are you referring to create-react-app?

Comment: Yes react scripts build ==> npm run build

Comment: should i use webpack for creating react production build. Will it improves my app loading time

Comment: Use `create-react-app` to generate a react project. Run `npx create-react-app app-name` to create the project, This will create a new project with webpack and everything setup for you to start creating the react app.

Comment: @Yousaf if i use create-react-app will it create webpack.config.js automatically ?

Comment: Yes, everything is set-up automatically. To build the project, you just need to run the command: `npm build`

Comment: @Yousaf i installed separately webpack module are you talking about that

Comment: With create-react-app, you don't need to install webpack separately.